# Refactor repetitively progress-bar's code segment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am showing a progress bar to the user for the tasks he needs to do for finishing up his profile.

I have this code-segment on several html.erb files:

```
  <% if progress < 100 %>
  <div>  
    <div class="progress progress-info progress-striped active">
      <div class="bar" style="width: <%= progress %>%"></div>
    </div>
     <div align="right"><u>Next</u>: <%=link_to nextUserTask, determinedpath %></div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

I think its ugly to repeat this code on all these files. Is there a way to refactor this? For example putting it into application_helper...

I tried to but I am not sure how to handle html in there.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put it in partial, for example `shared/_progress_bar.html.erb` and render it with:

```
<%= render 'shared/progress_bar', progress: progress, nextUserTask: nextUserTask, determinedpath: determinedpath %>
```

More about partials:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials